# How order of numpy array influence on multiplication speed?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cuda, matrix-multiplication

How order of numpy array influence on multiplication speed? And how I can auto choose it depending on size of matrices?

The question initially comes from code using cudamat:

```
def test_mat():
    #need to init cublas?
    # cm.cublas_init()

    n = 1024

    for i in xrange(1,20):  # 2^15 max or python fails
        m= 2
        m=m**i
        # print m
        print i
        try:
            t0= time.time()
            # cpum1 = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
            # cpum2 = np.array(np.random.rand(m, 1)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
            #CUDA need fortran order of array for speed?
            cpum1 = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')
            cpum2 = np.array(np.random.rand(m, 1)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')
            c = np.dot(cpum2.T, cpum1.T)
            print (time.time()-t0)

            t0= time.time()
            gpum1 = cm.CUDAMatrix(cpum1)
            gpum2 = cm.CUDAMatrix(cpum2)
            gm = cm.dot(gpum2.T, gpum1.T)
            gm.copy_to_host()
            print (time.time()-t0)
        except:
            pass

    # cm.cublas_shutdown()

    print 'done'
```

here is some tests I have done, but I need some theoretical point of view.

```
def test_order(m,n):            
    #default
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32)
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32)

    t0= time.time()
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    print (time.time()-t0)

    #1
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')

    t0= time.time()
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    print (time.time()-t0)

    #2
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')

    t0= time.time()
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    print (time.time()-t0)

    #3
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')

    t0= time.time()
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    print (time.time()-t0)

    #4
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')

    t0= time.time()
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    print (time.time()-t0)


    print 'done'    

m= 1024*10
n= 1024*1
7.125
7.14100003242
6.95299983025
8.14100003242
7.15600013733

m= 1024*1
n= 1024*10  
0.718999862671
0.734000205994
0.641000032425
0.656000137329
0.655999898911
```

Here is the code testing peak memory usage:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile    
def test_order_():

    m= 1024*1
    n= 1024*10

    #what used by default when c= np.dot(a,b)
    c = np.array(np.zeros((m, m)), dtype=np.float32, order='C')
    #c = np.array(np.zeros((m, m)), dtype=np.float32, order='F')

    #1
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')

    t0= time.time()
    c[:]= np.dot(a,b)
    # np.dot(a,b,out= c) # only for C-Array !
    print (time.time()-t0)

    del a
    del b
    # del c

    #2
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')

    t0= time.time()
    c[:]= np.dot(a,b)
    # np.dot(a,b,out= c) # only for C-Array !
    print (time.time()-t0)

    del a
    del b
    # del c

    #3
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='C')

    t0= time.time()
    c[:]= np.dot(a,b)
    # np.dot(a,b,out= c) # only for C-Array !
    print (time.time()-t0)

    del a
    del b
    # del c

    #4
    a = np.array(np.random.rand(m, n)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')
    b = np.array(np.random.rand(n, m)*10, dtype=np.float32, order='F')

    t0= time.time()
    c[:]= np.dot(a,b)
    # np.dot(a,b,out= c) # only for C-Array !
    print (time.time()-t0)

    del a
    del b
    # del c

    print 'done'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_order_()
```

Also found some info about numpy.dot copy and [fast_dot](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fb795ebef0e58bb672ebf3b519dcfe3d81e586d7/sklearn/utils/extmath.py)

> The internal workings of dot are a little obscure, as it tries to use
>   BLAS optimized routines, which sometimes require copies of arrays to
>   be in Fortran order

Also some [performance tips](http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformanceTips) it's strange but I can't reproduce results each time I run example.(Maybe before reruns some data chaches?)

Comment: If you automatically and arbritrarily change the ordering of your arrays between the C style and the FORTRAN style in your code then you are going to **seriously confuse people.**

Comment: if it's 2D only, then you could transform the matrix by .T method depending on the shape of matrix and then transform it back? I can imagine in some case it may worth doing.

Comment: @Ffisegydd the order only affects the memory layout. The API remains the same.

Comment: @otterb transpose of a matrix will only create a view, therefore the memory layout is the same.

Comment: Memory profiler only reports memory after each line. Whatever goes in the guts of numpy in the middle, will not be seen. Also, it is better to use the out argument: `np.dot(a, b, out=c)`.

Answer (score 3):

The performance depends on the underlying linear algebra library that you have.

```
# ORDER C-C    
In [6]: %timeit a.dot(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 87.6 ms per loop

# ORDER C-F
In [8]: %timeit a.dot(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 87.8 ms per loop

# ORDER F-C
In [10]: %timeit a.dot(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 90.1 ms per loop

# ORDER F-F
In [12]: %timeit a.dot(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 90 ms per loop
```

I am using ATLAS compiled on this machine with SSE3, as seen by `np.show_config()`. Re-running the computations show that there is no statistical difference between the two. And indeed, there is no difference because the library is doing a copy of the array before performing the product. Said copy takes 650 µs (including Python overhead), that is below the times you have. As the matrices grow, the dot product dominates, and you don't see the copy effect. If you use smaller matrices, the Python overhead masks any effect.

You can see the copies actually happening if you monitor the memory and use very large arrays.

Comment: "Make sure your output array is Fortran-ordered, however, otherwise  
copies will be made."  or you mean another copy?

Answer (score 1):

> How order of numpy array influence on multiplication speed? And how I can auto choose it depending on size of matrices?

I doubt it matters at all. The variation in your results is probably down to GC or other processes hogging CPU. Here are mine after disabling GC:

```
m= 1024*10
n= 1024*1
9.80310893059
9.8962469101
9.80171990395
9.8697450161
9.79560208321


m= 1024*1
n= 1024*10  
0.977525949478
1.00992393494
1.0397670269
0.990566015244
0.986133098602
```

Looks like it's all within variance (first two are measuring the same thing, since "C" is default).

Comment: I think it depends on cpu cache, try to increase matrix size.

Comment: @mrgloom, I went up to 3GB arrays and it's still within variance: 38.1636929512
37.9753510952
38.0870800018
38.0148370266
39.0343549252